# HERE Maps API for JS - create greyscale OSM layer

Tags: javascript, maps, openstreetmap, here-api, grayscale

I am using the HERE Maps API for Javascript v1.27.0. I have added an OSM layer using the `ImageTileProvider`:

```
const osmProvider = new H.map.provider.ImageTileProvider({
  getURL: (x: number, y: number, z: number): string => {
    return `https://tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png`;
  }
});
const osmLayer = new H.map.layer.TileLayer(osmProvider);
map.addLayer(osmLayer);
```

I am trying to convert the layer into a greyscale layer. I was wondering what is the best way to do this. I was hoping there would be some option in `H.map.provider.ImageTileProvider.Options`:

| Name | Description |
| --- | --- |
| onTileLoad | A function that is called on every tile when it is loaded. It gets the tile as an argument. It should return the modified tile. |

Which could then be used like this:

```
const osmProvider = ... ({
  onTileLoad: greyscale
});
const greyscale = (tile: H.map.provider.Tile): H.map.provider.Tile  => {
  // logic to convert normal tile to greyscale.
  return modifiedTile;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.